# W2CA possible loss of data, right?

Tags: c++, unicode, char, wchar-t, string-conversion

I'm working a legacy VC++6 app that is trying to add in unicode support, i have a function that calls into a rpc call that expects and unsigned char, if I use the W2CA() macro on the string being passed in, am i correct in assuming that there is a possibility of not being able to convert some unicode strings right? for example, I believe 我们的 T+G2 would be a problem. I just ask because I'm trying to decide if would be better off writing a wchar_t version.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you cannot expect Unicode to ANSI coversion to succeed with converting all the characters. You can use other encodings suchas UTF-8 instead of ANSI though.

A good [entry point into MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the question:

> lpDefaultChar [in]
>
> Optional. Pointer to the character to use if a character cannot be
>   represented in the specified code page. The application sets this
>   parameter to NULL if the function is to use a system default value. To
>   obtain the system default character, the application can call the
>   GetCPInfo or GetCPInfoEx function.

Comment: can utf-8 really handle all Unicode strings? and wouldn't you still have to use wchar_t for that?

Comment: Check this http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8 the table under "What is UTF-8?" gives a quick hint how UTF-8 covers 2^32 character range.